# Angular Apps, html5mode

Tags: html, angularjs

I am build an angular application, but run into some problem which i cannot refreshed the page.

Using XAMPP in locahost and the apps is located in `htdocs/myApps`

So i have to go to the main view to refresh page to get it working, however if i refreshed the page at other link lets say at  `http://localhost/myApps/good-incoming` the browser will sent me back to `http://localhost/dashboard` which is the dashboard of the xampp.

Tried to change the **.htaccess** file does not do any help.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /myApps/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, X-Auth-Token"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Put base tag in index.html `<base href="/myApps/">` do not solve the issue as well.

Where did i miss?

Comment: I don't know anything of the syntax of .htaccess, but you need a rule that makes your server serve your index.html for all the bookmarkable URLs (e.g. /myApps/good-incoming).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myApps/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#Change path of below line if you want consider last value of URL is parameter
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Then in your index file put `<base href="/" />` below the body tag

Comment: not working, now i cant access to the main view as well, it just show everything that is is not inside ng-view

Comment: Can you share your basic code by jsfiddle or any other tool, So we can look on that?

Comment: try this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/ANtilpLXPvomGN9pX9mW?p=preview not sure if it can run in plunker